# Rest Export JSON format

Tags: views

I'm new to Drupal and I've very excited about the possibly of headless as it will align with my current skillset and let me be productive more quicly while I continue to learn Drupal. (I come from a full stack .NET background using consuming REST services on the frontend).

I'm having some trouble with the JSON format.

I've set up a REST Export view in Drupal 8.3 that returns a custom content type. It includes a three fields: title, body(plain text), and an image.

The result that I get has a lot of escape characters and I'm not sure how to get it to just return the plain text data.

Here is the result that I get:

```
[{"title":"A test for the json api","field_body":"This is a test. It\u0026#039;s pretty awesome and I love you.","field_test_image":"\/drupal\/sites\/default\/files\/2017-04\/Adam_Dickison_1.png"}]
```

What I'd like to get back is this:

```
[{"title":"A test for the json api","field_body":"This is a test. It's pretty awesome and I love you.","field_test_image":"/drupal/sites/default/files/2017-04/Adam_Dickinson_1.png"}]
```

I've checked my php.ini and magic_quotes_gpc is set to 'Off'.

Can anybody help me figure this out. I didn't see any general settings. I've changed all of the field settings to remove html and to give me just the plain text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On your view page,  click on the 'Field settings'. i.e.

> **Format**:
>
> Show: Fields | Settings

Click on the '*Settings*'. You will see a popup window. And select the '**RAW OUTPUT**' for the respective field. Also, you can provide *ALIAS* for the field.

I guess you were looking for this option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to decode the unicode string on the client side.